# React router not matching base path

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Im practicing with react router and need to have an `:id` param. It matches with the an id in the url e.g. `/edit/2`  but not with the base case with just `/edit`.

**Main app router file**

```
import React from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter, Route, Switch, Link, NavLink} from 'react-router-dom';
import landingPage from '../components/landingPage';
import editPage from '../components/editPage';
import createPage from '../components/createPage';
import helpPage from '../components/helpPage';
import notFoundPage from '../components/notFoundPage';
import Header from '../components/header';


const AppRouter = () => (
    <BrowserRouter>
        <div>
            <Header/>
            <Switch>
                <Route exact={true} path="/" component={landingPage}/>
                <Route path="/create" component={createPage}/>
                <Route exact={false} path="/edit/:id" component={editPage}/>
                <Route path="/help" component={helpPage}/>
                <Route component={notFoundPage}/>
            </Switch>
        </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
);

export default AppRouter;
```

**editPage code**

```
import React from 'react';

const editPage = (props) => {
    console.log(props)
    return (
    <div>Edit Page</div>
    );
}
export default editPage;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are on React Router >= v4, you can [make a parameter optional](https://www.npmjs.com/package/path-to-regexp#optional) by adding a `?` after the parameter name:

```
<Route exact={false} path="/edit/:id?" component={editPage}/>
```

Comment: thats the problem! Where in the docs does it mention path-to-regexp dependency. Want to know the trail to the npm package